# Flatten a list of list with node values

Tags: list, scala, flatten

I am trying to perform the following action in scala but not sure how to proceed, in previous examples I have seen how to do a List of List like:

```
List(List(1,2), List(3,4)) -> List (1,2,3,4)
```

My problem is that I need to explode as well the results so I can flatten it to be stored on a hive table.

List **a** (1,List **b** (2,3))

Should look like:

```
1 , 2

1 , 3
```

Comment: How is that related to Spark in itself ? Do you want to perform that in a map operation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a for-comprehension :

```
val c = for (i <-a; j<- b) yield (i,j)
```

For example

`val a = List(1, 2, 3)
val b = List(4, 5, 6)
val c = for (i <- a; j <- b) yield (i, j)
println(c)`

will print `List((1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (3,4), (3,5), (3,6))`